# Reference a control on a form through a sub's parameters

Tags: vb.net

For a final project in my Visual Basic class, I am making a Windows Forms version of Battleship (I call it "NavalQuest" :p). There is a form for each player's board, and I have a .vb file for public shared information. In this file, I have a Public Shared Sub called "Place" to be called when ships are being placed. Here is what I have to head the sub:

```
Public Shared Sub Place(ByRef form As Form, ByRef board(,) As PictureBox, ByRef picbox As PictureBox)
```

Where "form" is the form from which the Sub is being called (either p1 or p2), "board(,)," the 2D array of picture boxes that is the actual board, and "picbox," the picture box on which the user wants to place the ship in question.

The user chooses a radio button, either "horizontal" or "vertical," which cooresponds with the orientation of the ship. The Sub checks which one is clicked. This is the reason I have a "form" parameter, to reference the form on which the radio button is, since I can't just reference it straight from the global .vb file. However, when the computer reads:

```
form.radhoriz.checked
```

It errors before I even try to run, because "radhoriz" is obviously not a property of Windows.System.Forms.Form. It doesn't understand that I'm going for a control ON the form, not a property of the Form itself. Even if I were to create a property on each form of "radhoriz," the error would still exist, since "radhoriz" would then be a property of "p1board" and "p2board" (the form names), not Windows.System.Forms.Form.

I tried changing the data type of the parameter to just an Object. There weren't any blue error lines popping up, so I ran the application. The runtime error came for the same reason as it had before.

Is there any way around this? I guess I could add parameters for all the controls I reference of the form, but is that the only way? Thanks for your help!

-Ryan

Comment: You should probably change the spelling of the application name, lest some unsuspecting users think they'll be exploring belly buttons.

Comment: Embarrising spelling mistake fixed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that it's a horrible overall design...
*Not unexpected, though, since you're a student!  =)

In your parameter signature...

Change:

```
ByRef form As Form
```

To:

```
ByRef form As frmName
```

Where "frmName" is the name of your player board form.

Also, change all the ByRef to ByVal.

Comment: Ohh, forgot that the form name becomes its own object type like that! Thanks! Yeah, I just had it as ByRef because I wasn't sure if I'd be changing anything on the form yet. Just out of curiosity, what would be a better design? Design is my weakest point overall lol, would love to improve in that!

Comment: Actually, scratch that, this approach actually doesn't work because the Sub is being called from TWO DIFFERENT FORMS...so calling it from player two's form would be checking the radio button on player one's form, or vice versa...

Comment: A better approach would be to separate your game representation and logic from your UI.  Create a class to hold the **state** of the game and you call methods against that.  The form(s) simply display the current state.

Comment: As for the last issue, there are several approaches.  (1) Make your forms implement an **Interface**, then change the type to that Interface; (2) Use Controls.Find() to search for the control with the correct name; (3) Use Reflection to access the controls.

Comment: I'm just going to use the Controls.Find() function for now, might see about upping the design if I have enough time haha...Thanks so much!

Comment: *You could also just check the TYPE of the form passed in and CAST the generic form to the correct type.